# Total questions number for a specific tag

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, design, custom-questions-list

For example, [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php).

> [image]

But on SOru we have it.

> [image]

Is it the bug, or intentionally removed?

Comment: @usr2564301 maybe this is the case https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312781/260198

Comment: If you go to https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/1991579 - I bet you're opted in to the custom question list stuff...

Comment: @JonClements yes. So? Should I report it here https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312781/260198?

Comment: @Suvitruf if no one else has noted it then it's probably worth doing that. It's not clear if it's by design or whether it's just been overlooked.

Comment: I reported this on MSE already [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/318997/323179) and it’s also reported as an answer to the one announcement.

Comment: A workaround for that is [adding `is:question`to the search string](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/384636/2751851).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue has been fixed, as reported [in the main Meta.SE Q&A about custom lists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/313983/242059):

> These numbers are back with today's update. – Brian Nickel♦ May 6 at 22:26