# When custom questions lists are enabled, how to quickly get the number of results when searching by tag?

Tags: support, tags, search, custom-questions-list

*The issue involving custom question lists described below has been fixed, so there is no longer a need for workarounds.*

For users that have opted-in to the [custom questions list feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312781/242059), the search results page does not display the number of results when the search is only based on tags (that is, without any keywords being specified). Having easy access to that information was quite convenient, especially when doing searches with multiple criteria (for instance, [`[c#][pattern-matching] -[regex]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23+pattern-matching+-regex)) as research for Meta discussions about tags.

Is there any non-SEDE workaround for quickly seeing the number of questions retrieved by a tag-based search?

Comment: That search shows the number of results for me...

Comment: @animuson Interesting... This is what I see when I click the link above: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXrG5.jpg

Comment: Ah, so it doesn't show up if you have custom question lists turned on. See, this is why I hate preferences.

Comment: @animuson Yup, that seems to be it. I will mention that in the question.

Comment: Related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378629/total-questions-number-for-a-specific-tag

Comment: @BhargavRao That is relevant, regardless of my suspicion the change was intentional (though that wasn't officially confirmed yet).

Answer (score 3):

One workaround is adding `is:question`, or equivalently `is:q`, to the search string, as in [`[c#][pattern-matching] -[regex] is:q`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+%5Bpattern-matching%5D+-%5Bregex%5D+is%3Aquestion). That will lead you to the "Search Results" page, which, unlike the "All Questions" page with custom lists, does show the number of results.

Comment: `is:q` is shorter and does the same thing.

Comment: @Laurel Thanks; added to the answer.